# Is it safe to ignore the "Has no specification file" warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, heroku, bundler

I recently ported my gem management to bundler, to get my app to play nice with heroku.  Upon doing so I started to see the following errors (though my app is running fine):

```
config.gem: Unpacked gem environment.rb in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem environment.rb in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory. Giving up.
config.gem: Unpacked gem ruby in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem ruby in vendor/gems not in a versioned directory. Giving up.
```

I have seen posts, saying that I can ignore them:
http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2009/03/configgem-unpacked-gem-whatever-in.html

Is that really the case, can I safely ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rails you should use something like:

`bundle_path 'vendor/bundler_gems'`

Rails 2.x expects the gems in its vendor/gems dir to have .specification files in them because that's where it stores its unpacked gems.

Comment: sorry for the delay -- lost this one in the shuffle -- thanks!

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't go in your Gemfile anymore, but is run when you call 'bundle install', i.e. bundle install /path/to/bundle.  

bundle_path is deprecated as of 0.9.5